# How can I get vue-loader to interpolate asset urls?

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

I have an image with a dynamic (interpolated) `src` attribute.

`<img src="./{{bar}}.jpg"/>`

How do I get vue-loader to interpolate `{{bar}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your code throws a warning (not referred it):

> [Vue warn]: src="./{{bar}}.jpg": interpolation in "src" attribute will cause a 404 request. Use v-bind:src instead.

So, you should bind the value:

```
<img :src="'/assets/' + bar + '.jpg'">
```

The above example it loads an image `xxx.jpg` from the static directory `assets`, but not via loader yet.

To accomplish that, you should use a [dynamic require](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html):

```
<img :src="loadImage(name)">

methods: {
  loadImage (imgName) {
    return require('./assets/' + imgName + '.jpg')
  }
}
```

> **NOTE**
>
> It is not recommended if the directory contains a large number of files, because the webpack will be load all the files which match your request (for the above example: `./assets/*.jpg`).

Comment: Evan Young goes into more detail in his response to my issue here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/251#issuecomment-224173671

Answer (score 0):

In attribute interpolation is not allowed, use v-bind instead

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes