# How can I bind a class attribute to an expression in Vue 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I had this in Vue 1.0:

```
<div v-for="menuItem in menu" class='vnav-item-wrapper'>
  <i v-show="menuItem.icon" class="vnav-icon fa fa-{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
</div>
```

But now the `{{}}` construct is obsolete in Vue 2.0.

I just read through the [Class and Style guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html) and it simply doesn't seem to be possible for me to bind a class to `"fa-" + menuItem.icon`. I can't bind to an expression.

The closest I got was calculated data properties but then again, I'm in the middle of a `v-for`, I can't  create "calculated variables".

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37667527/7376) shows you how. It was definitely not obvious to me that once you apply `v-bind:` (or the `:` short-hand) to an attribute it's all interpreted as though it were JavaScript. So I think what you want is:

```
<div v-for="menuItem in menu" class='vnav-item-wrapper'>
  <i v-show="menuItem.icon" :class="'vnav-icon fa fa-' + menuItem.icon"></i>
</div>
```