# Vue img src concatenate variable and text

Tags: mysql, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to concatenate Vue variable with image URL, but the browser didn't show the picture. Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

I have tried as follow. 
The picture didn't show in the browser.

```
<img :src="'../assets/'+item.picture">
```

If I wrote as below, the picture is shown.

```
<img src="../assets/6cb38c91115bcdf0c824124e4b5ecb71.jpeg">
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: depends entirely on what `item.picture` contains try making an example with a random google image then. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: I have checked the database 'item.picture' and '6cb38c91115bcdf0c824124e4b5ecb71.jpeg' are the same. Could you tell me why can the picture not show?

Comment: might be because it requires an absolute path on run time. so maybe changing it to `:src="'/assets/'+item.picture"` or (without the slash)`:src="'assets/'+item.picture"`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work...

Comment: Ah, the reason why the second method works is because the image is being loaded as `data:image`. If you want the first method to work, you will need the url of your server/webpage

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how do I do that? @A. Lau

Comment: you need to know where your image is being hosted, for example if it's `localhost:3000` then you will need to access it via `localhost:3000/assets/ + image.picture`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get vue-loader to interpolate asset urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667527/how-can-i-get-vue-loader-to-interpolate-asset-urls)